# Django keeps calling another package to paginate -- how?

Tags: python, django, pagination

My code imports `Paginator` from `django.core.paginator`.  (Django 1.6.7)

However, when run, somehow it is calling a custom paginator. I don't want it to do this, as the custom paginator template has been removed in an upgrade. I just want Django's `Paginator` to be used, but I can't find how to workout where it's overriding Django's `Paginator` with our broken one.

This may not be so much of a Django question and more of a generic Python question. All the usual things like grepping the code, inserting `ipdb`'s, judicious use of `find` etc yield no help.

Comment: And what is your settings.py file? what installed apps are there?

Comment: How do you mean, "calling" a custom paginator? How are you determining that? What is the symptom?

Comment: Look at your python library path beneath django folder in both /usr/lib/python_version/lib/django or /usr/local/lib/python_version/lib/django/..., if you are using linux machine for development? I faced this issue once and remove one of the custom paginator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've all been really helpful. However the my confusion came from the fact that  `paginator` was being added to the context, yet there was a statement `{% load paginator %}` at the top of the template. I thought they were the same, but no. The `paginator` from the context was unused, and the `load` statement pulled in the bad paginator, which was registered with the templating engine.

The fix is obvious: remove the `load` statement, including the context paginator and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure to not override the `Paginator` by it's name in the import

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator as DjangoPaginator
```

This will make sure that `DjangoPaginator` is coming from django itself and not get overridden by another class with the same name.

Then you can use it like the following

```
objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
p = DjangoPaginator(objects, 2)
```

---

If this works fine with you, then there must be a class with the name `Paginator` in your code that gets imported after django's class. Also a new virtual environment can be useful to determine wither the core django packages are modified or not.